# In need of a professional ASP .NET / MVC forum that allows integration with ASP .NET Identity / OWIN

Tags: .net, forum

Unfortunately and brilliant as they are, forums as yafnet and mvcforum are neither scalable nor decoupled enough to help me with my problem:

a) I want a forum that allows me to use different security systems, whether membership provider, simple provider, or (As is now) ASP .NET Identity with claims.

b) I have not found a free-source forum that allows me to do anything; wrapping a membership provider around ASP .NET Identity, would not work due to how OWIN works, disabling form/cookie authentication.

c) In light of such a dead end, I would like it if someone directs me to a product they have used that they know allows for strong customization in the register/login module, regardless of cost.

Thanks once more.